# Is a Program Running in Compatibility Mode

Tags: c++

Is there a C++ .NET function that I can call that will detect if my program is running in compatibility mode? If there is not one, could someone show me the code for one? Thanks.

For example:

Program loads up
Compatibility Mode check
if true then exit
else run

Comment: What do you mean by "compatibility"?

Comment: Users of all kinds will HATE you if you disable compatibility mode for your app. WHY would you want to do that?

Comment: Yeah disabling compatibility mode is quite restrictive

Answer (score 9):

From another forum

> After a few google searches went in
>   vain, I decided to experiment myself.
>   I found that the compatibility
>   settings for each executable are
>   stored - as I thought it would be - in
>   the windows registry.
>
> The key where the settings are stored
>   is
>   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows
>   NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers
>
> For each application that has its
>   compatibility settings specified,
>   there exists a value under that key
>   whose name is the path to the
>   executable and the data is a string
>   consisting of the compatibility
>   settings.
>
> The keywords in the string that
>   specify the compatibility settings
>   are:    WIN95    WIN98    NT4SP5
>   WIN2000    256COLOR    640X480
>   DISABLETHEMES    DISABLECICERO
>
> If multiple settings are specified (or
>   are to be specified), the data
>   consists of the settings above
>   separated by a space each. The first
>   four settings are mutually exclusive,
>   i.e. only one of them is to be
>   specified (if at all). I haven't
>   tested the consequences of specifying
>   multiple operating systems.
>
> So, back to addressing your problem.
>   To check if an executable (let's say,
>   "C:\path\executable.exe") is set to
>   run in 256 color mode, there would be
>   a value named "C:\path\executable.exe"
>   (without the quotes, even if the path
>   contains spaces) under the key
>   [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows
>   NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers],
>   and the data associated with the value
>   would contain the string "256COLOR".
>   If it is also set to run in
>   compatibility mode under Windows
>   98/ME, the data would be "WIN98
>   256COLOR".
>
> So, the approach is simple. Test if
>   there is a value with the full path of
>   the executable under the key I
>   mentioned above. If there isn't, the
>   executable has not been specified any
>   compatibility settings. If the value
>   exists, retrieve its data and check
>   for the presence of "256COLOR" in the
>   data. Accordingly, the presence of
>   "WIN95" or "WIN98" or "NT4SP5" or
>   "WIN2000" would mean that the
>   executable is set to run in
>   compatibility mode for that particular
>   operating system.

Comment: Cool, but in code, how would I check HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers for one of these values? Thanks!

Comment: The Registry and RegistryKey classes. Conceptually much the same to doing so the Windows API way rather than the .NET way.

Answer (score 4):

Get the version of the operation system that is returned from `GetVersionEx` and compare it to the file version on `kernel32.dll`. When in application compatibility mode `GetVersionEx` will always return the version of the operating system that is being 'emulated'. If both versions are different then you are in application compatibility mode.

Answer (score 2):

The answer above helped me to get a *"solution"* for the question at hand. It is probably not the most elegant, but seems to work. Obviously you can get a bit more creative on the return type. Booleon does not suffice here. I think a native API would be good.

```
typedef VOID (NTAPI* TRtlGetNtVersionNumbers)(LPDWORD pdwMajorVersion, LPDWORD pdwMinorVersion, LPDWORD pdwBuildNumber);

bool IsRunningCompatMode()
{
    TRtlGetNtVersionNumbers RtlGetNtVersionNumbers = (TRtlGetNtVersionNumbers)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA("ntdll.dll"), "RtlGetNtVersionNumbers");

    assert(RtlGetNtVersionNumbers);

    if(RtlGetNtVersionNumbers)
    {
        OSVERSIONINFO osInfo = {0};
        osInfo.dwOSVersionInfoSize = sizeof(OSVERSIONINFO);
        GetVersionEx(&osInfo);

        DWORD dwMajorVersion;
        DWORD dwMinorVersion;
        DWORD dwBuildNumber;

        RtlGetNtVersionNumbers(&dwMajorVersion, &dwMinorVersion, &dwBuildNumber);

        dwBuildNumber &= 0x0000FFFF;

        if(osInfo.dwBuildNumber != dwBuildNumber)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
};
```