# How check if program is running in compatible mode and display mode in title bar

Tags: c#

My program need to be run in XP compatible mode. I need  A way to check if is running in XP compatible mode. If not tell the user to run it in compatible mode. I have searched but found no answer. I have tried this `this.Text = System.Environment.OSVersion.VersionString;` but it returns Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 not the emulated XP.

(Edit)

After more searches and dll imports nothing worked right it would always returns Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1. So I created A console loaded to handle registry then run my program.

```
using System;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using Microsoft.Win32;

[assembly: RegistryPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.RequestMinimum, ViewAndModify = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER")]

class RegKey
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int Major = Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major;
        int Minor = Environment.OSVersion.Version.Minor;

        if (Major == 5 && Minor == 1)
        {   
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\MyApp.exe");
        }
        else if (Major > 5)
        {
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\MyApp.exe"))
            {
                RegistryKey Rkey = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\AppCompatFlags\\Layers");
                //Creates Name And Value
                Rkey.SetValue(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\MyApp.exe", "WINXPSP3");
                //Starts App.
                 System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\MyApp.exe", "Load");

                //Waites 500 milliseconds so my program can get the registry info
                //(Not needed any more) 
                //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);

                //Deletes Name And Value
                //(Handled by MyApp.exe to increase load time)
                //Rkey.DeleteValue(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\MyApp.exe");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("File Not Found!!!");
                Console.WriteLine("( MyApp.exe ) Must Be In Same Directory As The Loader.exe.");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I handle registry in this way so my program can be portable and prevent registry entries that point to nothing. I am shore that they are better ways to get the results I was looking for.

(Edit 2)

After more checking I only have to run XP compatible mode on 64 bit systems. 32 bit systems do not need to run in XP compatible mode. I compiled my app with platform x86. So it must has something to do with the way 64 bit systems read the registry.

Comment: Hard to imagine why you'd need to run in compat mode. What does your app do wrong?

Comment: You'll need to use unmanaged code to do this but if your app is doing something that requires Compat Mode you're likely already doing that somewhere else :)

Comment: Please have a look at the following question that i noticed on SO [Is a Program Running in Compatibility Mode](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3445031/1012641)

Comment: [Application compatibility layers are there for the customer, not for the program](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/03/11/9976571.aspx): "it's there to clean up after your mistakes, not to let you hide behind them."

Comment: My app uses parts form an older app. If my app is not run in XP compatible mode it doesn't work right. It is not my app that has the problem.

Comment: Yes, 64-bit systems do not store files in the same place in the registry as 32-bit applications. You should ask a new question about how to fix your app, rather than hacking around it. Disabling registry redirection might be an option.